# I usually get this error when I try to install gems

Tags: rubygems, gsl

I'm new to Ruby and Gems, so I might be missing something that's obvious:

```
ERROR:  Error installing matlab-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

I've gotten the error for several Gems, among them Ruby GSL.

I'm running Mac OS 10.7.2, Ruby 1.8.7, and XCode 4.2, if that matters.

Full console output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gsl:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1: command not found: gsl-config --version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:237: Check GSL>=0.9.4 is installed, and the command "gsl-config" is in search path. (RuntimeError)
checking gsl version... 

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gsl-1.14.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gsl-1.14.7/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message. It usually contains information about the failure reason.

Comment: I came across this post while searching for a solution for OS X - in case someone else has the same issue, instructions in [this post](http://hi.baidu.com/rainchen/item/e9f24fc009c227340831c6a2) helped me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got gsl installed!

The important thing is to install the version of gsl that matches the version of rb-gsl you are using, in my case 1.14.

For those who know nothing about compiling crap in c like me:

Download and unzip your gsl package
Navigate to that folder in the terminal
Type these commands:

```
./configure
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

The make install command I guess installs it to the standard location?

Once I did that,

```
sudo gem install gsl
```

worked just fine!

I also found this great intro article about installing gems with native extensions and what the heck all this stuff is actually doing:

http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/31/dont-be-terrified-of-building-native-extensions